# GraphQL so is it possible to determine the Types that will be return dynamically based on the query Parameter in?

Tags: graphql

like the title said but i came accros the fact that my front part does not know anything about GraphQL , so is it possible to determine the Types that will be return dynamically based on the query Parameter in?

Answer (score 1):

You can query the field "__typename" on objects, interfaces and unions.

Comment: Thanks , but Yes i have done it but it is not fullfilling my needs , look what i want to do is to be able to generate a Paginate Type or a simple Type , by specifying a parameter in my Query Parameter .
Union and Interfaces you should always specifying the Type wether the Union Type or the Type which is going to implements the Interface , but that's not what i want 
And i do not know if it is possible